# Sequential grouping using Oracle SQL 10.2

Tags: sql, oracle

I'm struggling with some SQL select and need your help.
I'm dealing with this kind of data:

```
key1    key2    key3    id  attr
550928  *   *   5   2225
550928  *   *   6   4060
550928  *   *   10  7125
550928  *   *   20  7105
550928  *   *   22  2220
550928  *   *   25  7125
550928  *   *   30  7110
550928  *   *   35  7110
550928  *   *   40  7110
550928  *   *   50  7110
550928  *   *   60  7110
550928  *   *   70  7110
550928  *   *   80  7110
550928  *   *   90  7110
550928  *   *   100 7110
550928  *   *   110 7110
550928  *   *   115 7110
550928  *   *   120 7110
550928  *   *   130 7110
550928  *   *   140 7110
550928  *   *   150 7110
550928  *   *   155 7110
550928  *   *   170 2220
550928  *   *   190 4160
550928  *   *   210 4160
550928  *   *   220 2225
550928  *   *   225 2220
550928  *   *   999 2220
```

What I want to get is something like this

```
key1    key2    key3    id  attr
550928  *   *   5   2225
550928  *   *   6   4060
550928  *   *   10  7125
550928  *   *   20  7105
550928  *   *   22  2220
550928  *   *   25  7125
550928  *   *   30 - 155    7110
550928  *   *   170 2220
550928  *   *   190  - 210  4160
550928  *   *   220 2225
550928  *   *   225 - 999   2220
```

So to group sequentially over attr but line after line, not in the whole set. 
I tried something like this but it doesn't seem to work as planned:

```
select key1,
       key2,
       key3,
       attr,
       min_id,
       max_id
  from (select soo.key1,
               soo.key2,
               soo.key3,
               soo.attr,
               soo.id,
               min(soo.id) keep(dense_rank first order by soo.key1, soo.key2, soo.key3, lpad(soo.id, 5, '0')) over(partition by soo.key1, soo.key2, soo.key3, soo.attr) min_id,
               max(soo.id) keep(dense_rank last order by soo.key1, soo.key2, soo.key3, lpad(soo.id, 5, '0')) over(partition by soo.key1, soo.key2, soo.key3, soo.attr) max_id
          from my_table soo)
 where (id = min_id or id = max_id)
 order by min_id;
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

May that helps, but it is untested:

```
SELECT key1,
       key2,
       key3,
       attr,
       min(id) min_id,
       max(id) max_id
  FROM my_table
 GROUP
    BY key1, 
       key2, 
       key3, 
       attr
 ORDER
    BY 5
```

Answer (score 0):

Have a try with row_number() :

```
SELECT KEY,
     CASE WHEN MIN(ID) = MAX(ID) 
          THEN TO_CHAR(MIN(ID)) 
          ELSE MIN(ID)||'-'||MAX(ID) 
     END AS grouped_id,
     attr
FROM
     (SELECT key,id,attr,
          row_number() OVER( ORDER BY ID) - row_number() OVER( PARTITION BY attr ORDER BY ID) grp
     FROM your_table
     )
GROUP BY KEY, attr, grp
ORDER BY MIN(id);
```

You'll get a result as below:

```
key    grouped_id attr
----------------------
550928  5         2225
550928  6         4060
550928  10        7125
550928  20        7105
550928  22        2220
550928  25        7125
550928  30-155    7110
550928  170       2220
550928  190-210   4160
550928  220       2225
550928  225-999   2220
```